# Are there any words that are similar to anglophile but is for other countries?

Tags: word-request

I recently learned the word *anglophile*. I want to know are there any any words that are similar to *anglophile* but for other countries? Thanks.

Comment: I could be a [**Francophile**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/francophile).

Comment: It’s not in the dictionary yet, but I have heard and used Japanophile.

Comment: Also Sinophile isn't in Lexico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Etymologically](https://www.etymonline.com/word/Anglophile),

> **Anglophile** = **Anglo-** + **-phile**
>
> **Anglo-** = of or pertaining to England or the English
>
> **-phile** = one that loves, likes, or is attracted to

Similarly, there are [germanophiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanophile), [francophiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francophile), [sinophiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinophile), [hispanophiles](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hispanophile), [indophiles](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Indophile), [americanophiles](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Americanophile) and so on.

Comment: My cousin is a lusophile (loves Portugal).